# Cannot convert value of type 'Option' to expected argument type '@noescape (Option) throws -> Bool'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, realm

I have a class called `Option`. This is a Realm object so it's a subclass of Realm's own base class `Object`.

In a view controller I have an array  property that holds a bunch of `Option` objects.

```
private var options = [Option]()
```

In a method down the view controller, I need to check if a certain `Option` object is contained within the aforementioned options array.

Previously (Swift 1.2), I have the checking logic like this.

```
func itemSelected(selection: Object) {
    let option = selection as! Option

    if !contains(options, option) {
        // act accordingly
    }
}
```

Now I'm converting the project to Swift 2 (I have updated the Realm's version to Swift 2 version as well). I updated the code to this.

```
func itemSelected(selection: Object) {
    let option = selection as! Option

    if !options.contains(option) {
        // act accordingly
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting the following compile error!

**Cannot convert value of type 'Option' to expected argument type '@noescape (Option) throws -> Bool'**

I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the `contains` function now expects a closure rather than an element on all non-equatable types. All you need to do is change it to the following

```
if !(options.contains{$0==option}) {
    // act accordingly
}
```

What this does is it passes a closure in to the function, which returns true only if that closure satisfies any of its elements. `$0` stands for the current element in the array that the `contains` function is testing against, and it returns true if that element is equal to the one that you are looking for.

Comment: Note that there are *two* contains methods: one takes a single element, and the other takes a closure.

Comment: @MartinR apparently the single element one only works on `Equatable` types now.

Comment: Exactly! You should add that to the answer, otherwise it is misleading.

Comment: @MartinR the reason that it wasn't there at first was because I tested the code in my project on a non equatable type. Had I tested on an array of `String`s maybe I would have known earlier

Answer (score 1):

While the first answer, that indicates this issue occurs because the `contains` method needs to operate on an `Equatable` type, is true, that's only half the story. The Realm `Object` class inherits `NSObject`, which conforms to `Equatable` (thus this should work without a closure). For more discussion on this, you can refer to this issue on the Realm GitHub page: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2519. The Realm developers indicate that they believe this is a bug in Swift.

Ultimately, the suggested workaround is to re-declare the conformance to `Equatable` and `Hashable`, like so (this is copied verbatim from GitHub user bdash's comment on the previously posted issue):

```
public class A: Object, Equatable, Hashable {
}

public func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqual(rhs)
}
```

You'd replace the all instances of type `A` with type `Option` in that sample.

I've tested this solution, and it works for me in XCode 7.2.1, using Swift version 2.1.1.